# Can I use parent.postMessage on redirected iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to use the window.parent.postMessage function, however, I want it to be used on a redirected iframe.  Here is the scenario:

Let's say that our browser is at http://mytestsite.com and it has an iframe inside of it which is initially set at http://othersite.com

to be more accurate, the iframe is set to http://othersite.com?redirect-url=http://mytestsite.com

(except the redirect site URL would be HTML encoded)

what happens is, some stuff gets done on othersite.com and then othersite.com eventually redirects itself to mytestsite.com.  When this happens I thought I would be able to do this:

```
window.parent.postMessage({
    'someData': 'whatever'
}, window.location.ancestorOrigins[0]);
```

and then this on the parent:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  console.log('do something with: ', e);
});
```

However, this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I did not fully understand the situation.  In my question I simplified the problem but in real life this is what I had.

Main browser window:  http://10.1.20.61:4200/console/payments

Note: this is an Angular 5 app.  The IP address listed here is the local IP of my machine on the network here at work.

redirected iframe: http://localhost:4200/cc-auth-process

There were two problems that I had to solve here.  First thing I noticed was when I went to do an ng build on this the build blew up because it said that window.location did not have a property of ancestorOrigins.  I still don't know why this blew up though because at least in my case (in the Chrome browser) window.location did have an ancestorOrigins property which was an array of URLs.

Anyhow looking at this is what made me realize that the parent was in fact a different domain than the iframe.  To fix this I added an environment variable and used this instead, which in turn allowed the postMessage to propagate to the parent.